# Why does $ab=ba=1$ imply ${a_1}^2 + {a_2}^2 + {a_3}^2 + {a_4}^2 = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces, quaternions

Let's say that I've got a group $V$ of integer quaternions of the form $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}i  + \mathbb{Z}j + \mathbb{Z}k$.  Now assume that there exists an element $a = a_1 + a_2i + a_3j + a_4k$ such that $ab=ba=1$ for some other element $b \in V$.  Note also that Why would this imply that ${a_1}^2 + {a_2}^2 + {a_3}^2 + {a_4}^2 = 1$?

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that the usual norm $||\,\cdot\,||$ on $\Bbb H$ is compatible with quaternionic multiplication in the sense that $||ab|| = ||a||\,||b||$.

Comment: Yes I can see that and understand it but how do i use that fact to show this?

Comment: I just don't see how this follows from that fact?

Comment: Combine this fact with the observation that for any nonzero $a \in V$ we have $||a|| \geq 1$.

Comment: In fact, it seems that $ab = 1$ is enough, so we can drop the additional hypothesis that $ab = ba$ (which gives a strictly stronger condition).

Answer (score 5):

As Travis said in the comments,

$$\| a b\| = \| a\| \| b\|$$,

in this case we have $ab=1$ so we can write,

$$ 1 = \|a\| \|b\|$$,

and if we square both sides we can write,

$$ 1 = (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2+b_4^2).$$

All the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers. We then have that the product of two integers is equal to $1$. Under what circumstances is this possible?